# empty object passed on props from nowhere

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

Im passing props on react and in certain point, I get an empty object on them. This is a problem since I'll have to use the map function and "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". The first log is from the parent class, the other four (should be three ?) are from its children. Please ignore the errors related with the key. I dont get this error if I dont call the TabsArea component, but thats not a solution.

My app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Modelo3d from './Modelo3d/Modelo3d'
import Options from './Options/Options';
import ThumbnailAreas from './ThumbnailArea/ThumbnailAreas';
import ThumbnailArea from './ThumbnailArea/ThumbnailArea';
import TabsArea from './TabsArea/TabsArea';

    import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'
    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {

                activeTab: 'Tab 1',

                thumbnails: [
                    {
                        tituloThumbnail: 'Costas',
                        texturas: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    },
                    {
                        tituloThumbnail: 'Pernas',
                        texturas: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
                    },
                    {
                        tituloThumbnail: 'Pés',
                        texturas: ['A', 'B'],
                    }
                ],

                tabs: [
                    {
                        tituloTab: 'Tab 1',
                        colecoes: ['Colecao 1', 'Colecao 2', 'Colecao 3', 'Colecao 4', 'Colecao 5', 'Colecao 6', 'Colecao 7', 'Colecao 8'],
                    },
                    {
                        tituloTab: 'Tab 2',
                        colecoes: ['Colecao 1'],
                    },
                    {
                        tituloTab: 'Tab 3',
                        colecoes: ['Colecao 1', 'Colecao 2', 'Colecao 3'],
                    },
                    {
                        tituloTab: 'Tab 4',
                        colecoes: ['Colecao 1', 'Colecao 2', 'Colecao 3', 'Colecao 4'],
                    }
                ]
            };
        }

        changeActiveTab(tab) {
            this.setState({activeTab: tab});
        }

        activeTabContent() {
            const activeIndex = this.state.tabs.findIndex((tab) => {
                return tab.tituloTab === this.state.activeTab;
            });

            return this.state.tabs[activeIndex].colecoes;
        }

        render() {

            return (
                <div className={"container is-fluid"}>

                    <section>
                        <Modelo3d/>
                        <hr className={"line"}/>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <Options>

                            <ThumbnailAreas thumbnailAreas={this.state.thumbnails}
                            />

                            <hr className={"line"}/>

                            <TabsArea
                                activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
                                tabList={this.state.tabs}
                                changeActiveTab={this.changeActiveTab.bind(this)}
                                key={this.state.activeTab}
                                colecoes={this.activeTabContent()}/>

                        </Options>
                    </section>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

The props console.log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `ThumbnailAreas` component added this line of code

```
if(!this.props.thumbnails){
  return <div>loading</div>
}
return(
// your map function goes here this.props.thumbnails.map(item=>.......
)
```

Comment: wow, it worked, thanks ! Can you explan me why the empty object ?

Comment: @NelsonSilva can you accept it as an answer please , I will explain the issue : the things with react the render methode get executed no mather what the value of the props , so it take some times before the props get passed that why you need to wait a litle bit before executing the return value

Comment: done ! so, it could also be done in the componentdidmount ?

Comment: @NelsonSilva yeah but their is no need to move it to componentdidmount because the render methode get executed on the componentdidmount , the good practice is to use it as i did show you in the answer

Comment: also dont forget to added a key to each value that you mapped

Comment: yeap Ill deal with the key issue. Oh ok I see, thanks for the explanation !